# Как писать и выполнить новую команду в первом запущенном процессе cmd по условию не создавая новый процесс в C#?

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
string command1 = comanda"; //Команда 1

// создаем процесс 1
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo1 =
new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd" , st + command1);
System.Diagnostics.Process pr1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
procStartInfo1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pr1.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
pr1.Start();

procStartInfo1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo1.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo1.CreateNoWindow = true;

pr1.WaitForExit();

if (условие)
   {
string command2 = comanda"; //Команда 2

// создаем процесс 2
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo2 =
new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd" , st + command2);
System.Diagnostics.Process pr2 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
procStartInfo2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pr2.StartInfo2 = procStartInfo2;
pr2.Start();

procStartInfo2.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo2.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo2.CreateNoWindow = true;

pr2.WaitForExit();
   }
   else
   {
       pr2.WaitForExit();
   }
```

так работает но создается новый процесс под вторую команду, а надо чтобы вторая команда выполнялась на первом же процессе/cmd , как это делается подскажите пожалуйста, пробовал по разному но без нового процесса не как не получается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
Process pr1 = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ping", "google.com");
//startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
//startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
//startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pr1.StartInfo = startInfo;

pr1.Start();
pr1.WaitForExit();

if (true)
{
    startInfo.Arguments = "2ip.ru";
    pr1.Start();
    pr1.WaitForExit();
}
```

Или вот так:

```
var command = "/C ping google.com";
if (true)
{
    command += "& ping 2ip.ru";
}

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", command);
//startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
//startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
//startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process pr1 = Process.Start(startInfo);
pr1.WaitForExit();
```